# cmp - What's the content of FLAGS register after do this compare

Tags: x86, cpu

if the cpu do:

```
cmp 0x80000000, 0x80000001
```

What's the content of the FLAGS register?

I have thought the process should be like below:

do:

tmp = -0x80000000 = 0x80000000 (Overflow)

result = 0x80000001 + tmp = 0x1 (Overflow)

So, OF = 1, SF = 0...
However, it's wrong. I'm so confused.

Comment: Errr... I would expect this not even to compile, since the instruction contains two immediate values, which is not normally acceptable (and doesn't make any sense, anyway)

Comment: @PMF ...I don't mean it have do this straightly... like '$eax = 0x80000001', then do `cmp 0x80000000, $eax'

Comment: Why not try it in your debugger?

Comment: Good guide to help you understand overflow(signed) vs. carry(unsigned):  http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt

Comment: @PeterCordes It's exactly what I want!

Comment: "tmp = -0x80000000 = 0x80000000 (Overflow)" never happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After executing (your code in AT&T-style syntax):

```
mov $0x80000000, %eax    # -2147483648
cmp $0x80000001, %eax    # -2147483648 - (-2147483647)
```

The eflags register's bits for [ CF PF AF SF IF ] will be set. That's exactly the same as if you executed `sub $0x80000001, %eax`. In this case, `%eax` will have the result `0xffffffff`, or `-1` as a signed 32 bit integer.

By calculating `-2147483648 - (-2147483647)`, there is no overflow, because you do not cross the border of `-2147483648` downwards. Instead, you go upwards by so much that you end up at `-1`.

**UPDATE:**
If you exchange the operands, so if you do `-2147483647 - (-2147483648)`, you do something very similar as before: You calculate x - (negative number), which goes upwards, not downwards. Thus, there is again no downwards crossing of `-2147483648`, and again there is no overflow. The result is `1`.

Note that `x - (negative number)` is not always the same as `x + (-(negative number))`. When subtracting or comparing, the calculation is done directly. There is no pre-conversion of the negative number to a positive number.

Comment: Thank you! But what if `mov $0x80000001, %eax       cmp $0x80000000, %eax'?

Comment: @ATlaS: update your question to make it clear whether it's AT&T syntax or Intel syntax.  e.g. `cmp eax, edx  ; eax=INT_MIN  edx=INT_MIN+1`   or   `cmp %eax, %edx  # eax=INT_MIN  edx=INT_MIN+1`, then someone can answer the case you want.  Or just work it out for yourself following the logic this answer gives.